# Class Attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, scope, attributes

I am trying to understand the scope of attributes and methods in Python classes.

while trying this piece of code:

```
class A:  
   mutable = {}
   number =10

   def change(cls):
       cls.mutable[cls] = "true"
       cls.number = cls.number +10
       print (cls.mutable)
       print (cls.number)

obj1 = A()
obj2 = A()

print (obj1.change())
print (obj1.change())
print (obj1.change())


print(obj2.change())
print (obj2.change())
print (obj2.change())
```

while "number" attributes is showing object-level scope ie.
Dictionary object is not.

Can anyone help? It will be great help

Here is the output of Following code

```
{<__main__.A object at 0x000002101CB3B940>: 'true'}
20
None
{<__main__.A object at 0x000002101CB3B940>: 'true'}
30
None
{<__main__.A object at 0x000002101CB3B940>: 'true'} 
40
None
{<__main__.A object at 0x000002101CB3B940>: 'true', <__main__.A object at 0x000002101CBA6630>: 'true'}
20
None
{<__main__.A object at 0x000002101CB3B940>: 'true', <__main__.A object at 0x000002101CBA6630>: 'true'}
30
None
{<__main__.A object at 0x000002101CB3B940>: 'true', <__main__.A object at 0x000002101CBA6630>: 'true'}
40
None
```

Comment: Take note that ``def change(cls):`` is a regular method, not a ``classmethod`` – it receives the instance (commonly known as ``self``) as the sole argument, not the class. While ``cls.mutable`` is at "object-level scope", it has a separate entry for each instance.

Comment: Thanks Brother.. Got It..Its really confusing between self and cls initially..

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the difference between mutable and immutable objects.

Your variable `mutable` is a mutable `dict`. Your variable `number` is an immutable `int`.

Lets start with your class definition.

```
class A:  
    mutable = {}
    number = 10
```

Here you set 2 class attributes. Since only one of these is mutable, only one will continue to be the same object after you modify it.

Next lets talk about your method.

```
    def change(cls):
        cls.mutable[cls] = "true"
        cls.number = cls.number + 10
        print(cls.mutable)
        print(cls.number)
```

Here, your `cls` variable is a bit deceiving. As @MisterMiyagi mentioned, this isn't a class method. Typically we would name the implicit instance variable that is passed in `self`. Naming it `cls` will not change the behavior of it since there is nothing special about the name `self`. It's just common practice to use that name.

Another point of importance here is that while this line `cls.mutable[cls] = "true"` mutates the existing class attribute, this one `cls.number = cls.number + 10` creates a fresh object and assigns it to the instance, since `cls` actually refers to the instance in this case.

So in summary, on you first call of the `change` method. `cls.number = cls.number + 10` assigns an instance attribute equal to the class attribute plus 10.

Of course you can alter this behavior by giving it the `@classmethod` decorator which will pass the class implicitly instead of the instance.

```
    @classmethod
    def change(cls):
        cls.mutable[cls] = "true"
        print(id(cls.number))
        cls.number = cls.number + 10
        print(id(cls.number))
```